# How to add a serial number to my usb stick

Tags: usb, serial-number

I have a cheap usb stick. Unfortunately my stick has no serial number.

Is it possible to add an own serial number to my stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in general.  To change the USB descriptors and add a USB serial number, you would have to modify the firmware of the USB stick.  It's unlikely that the procedure for writing to it would be documented, or that the firmware itself would be available in source form.  The effort it takes to figure that stuff out probably outweighs the cost of just buying a better USB device.

Also, why do you need a serial number?  Perhaps you can store a UUID of some sort in the filesystem of the USB drive instead of in the firmware of the drive itself.

However, this link about reprogramming USB devices might be useful:

https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/10/06/badusb-now-with-do-it-yourself-instructions/

Comment: "Also, why do you need a serial number? Perhaps you can store a UUID of some sort in the filesystem of the USB drive instead of in the firmware of the drive itself."

I need a serial for "pamusb". I would like to login on my pc without a password.
On github theres a issue, that describe, usb sticks without serial are not working.